# Can I use logos of brands, companies and/or services in a website for linking to my content on those services?

Tags: internet, trademark, austria

Specifically, can I use the youtube logo on my website as a button to link to a video on youtube that I made?

What if I trace the logo, and/or change it a little to fit with the general theme of the website, e.g. crop it to a square shape? Or if I trace the logo badly, and it ends up similar, but not 100% the same (e.g., the gradient is slightly off)?

Should I declare anything specific on my website?

What if I use e.g. the Apple Logo to link to Apple Music (which has a different Logo)?

And the last, maybe most important question: What if I do it anyway? Can I expect a takedown request, a full-on lawsuit, or nothing at all?

P.S.: I'm based in austria, but please still answer the question if you're only knowledgable in other countries' law systems, since I think this may also be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Since YouTube expects people to link to their site, they have guidelines on what are acceptable methods. You *should not* alter the logo, instead use a recommended logo from their website, or follow their rules for creating a customized logo that meets their requirements.

https://www.youtube.com/intl/en-GB/about/brand-resources/#logos-icons-colors

Apple is more complicated:

https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html